# Can job seekers perform searches on careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, jobs, search

... I'd like to do some searches to see how my skills profile matches up with the rest of the market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We only allow searches from legitimate companies who are actually hiring -- and even then, only if they pay to subscribe:

- 1 week subscription is $500
- 1 month subscription is $1,000
- 6 month subscription is $3,000
- 1 year subscription is $5,000

So ... found a company! Paul Graham will be so pleased with you! :)

Comment: what about the "demo" Joel talks about on his blog? Can we try it even if we are job seeker?

Comment: yes, as long as you don't try to mix employer and candidate openids

Comment: So you can't do an employer demo/free search from an existing account? If true, then that sounds dumb. OK so accounts are free, but why should users have to bother with the hassle of having to set up another OpenID and switch in/out each time?

Comment: A 'search from a legitimate company' is really a search from someone working there who works on recruitment. In our company's case, that's me, and I'm also a programmer who has a CV. Too bad I don't get to try the employer demo.

Answer (score 3):

If not specific searches, then it would certainly be useful to be able to compare yourself to the market. How many other people claim similar skillsets to yours, how many other people are in your area, how many searches that turned you up also turned others - and perhaps then what searches did you narrowly miss out on? Like a Google search summarising the numbers of other answers. If there are 20 similar developers to you in your area, you'll know to try harder to add details that set you apart.

The central premise for careers.so is to try to match people with jobs? Shouldn't it be offering the people the tools to be attractive to searchers.

This isn't (just) about gaming the system. Searchers still need to trust the results and that seekers are not fabricating skills they don't actually have, but the best way of improving your CV is by being told what it isn't showing (but could) or what you might not consider important, but apparently is something that people are currently looking for.

Comment: I'd certainly like some kind of numerical feedback on the things I can and want to do. If I find that what I'm seeking is laughably unlikely - at least it tells me to give up and target something more viable.